# функция после await не дожидается выполнения промиса

Tags: javascript

**await** должен по сути ждать пока отработает промис справа и затем вызывать функцию **createMapAndRoute()**, подскажите, что я наворотил не так

```
async function coordinatesOfPoints(arr) {
  const url = `https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=`
  const appiKey = '...'

  const result = []
  console.log(result.length) 

  await new Promise((res, rej) => {
    arr.forEach(async (item) => {
      const request = await fetch(`${url}${appiKey}&geocode=${item}`)
      const response = await request.json()

      let coordinate =
        response.response.GeoObjectCollection.featureMember[0].GeoObject.Point
          .pos
      coordinate = coordinate
        .split(' ')
        .map((item) => (item = +item))
        .reverse()
      result.push(coordinate)
    })
    res()
  })
  console.log(result)  //пустой массив, а хотелось бы массив с результатами
  createMapAndRoute(result)
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Вы разрешаете промис *мгновенно*, вызвав `res()`. И на сколько я помню, в forEach async await не очень работает. Попробуйте переписать цикл на for

Comment: @wchistow я в коде написал, что хотелось бы в результат получить массив с результатами от запроса, но выводится пустой

Comment: @SwaD не совсем понял, что вы имеете ввиду, куда я в таком случае resolve поставлю? или мне без промиса это сделать? и у внешней получается убрать async/await?

Comment: Тебе нужно создать массив промисов и запустить их в `Promise.all()` - результатом будет как раз массив с ответами от каждого промиса. По окончании обработки ответа вызвать результирующий `res()`.